# Знаки побитового сдвига в потоках ввода/вывода

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

В *C++* есть такие стандартные операторы ввода и вывода:

```
cin >> x;
```

и

```
cout << x;
```

Какую роль здесь играют знаки побитового сдвига? Зачем их необходимо указывать при поточном вводе и выводе?

Comment: это переопределённые операторы, в С++ свои операторы вводить нельзя, надо использовать что есть, а эти чем-то напонимают пайпы, поэтому привычны и глаза не режут.

Comment: @Ilnyr а как бы Вы их реализовали?

Comment: @perfect а как их можно использовать?)

Comment: @pavel с этими операторами у новичков почти всегда не разбериха потому что они в процессе изучения не владеют контекстом в котором применяются эти стандартные операторы. Поэтому я бы если создавал стандарт языка применил отдельные операторы отличные от стандартных.

Comment: @perfect угу а ещё можно сразу cin.print(x); сделать на шаблонной магии, вот только зачем...

Comment: @pavel зато такой подход дает свободу, правда так же это породит исбыточность, но от нее можно и отказаться при желании

Answer (score 10):

Операторы побитового сдвига указывают в какую сторону **двигать** двоичное число, т.е. применяется к числам. А в контексте потоков они принимают другой смысл потому, что слева уже не число, а поток у которого эти операторы перегружены и значат они `<<` - **двигать** информацию в поток и `>>` - **двигать** информацию из потока.

Answer (score 7):

Оператор `>>` или `<<` это всего лишь бинарные операторы, а делать они могут то, что определил программист. Для целых чисел эти операторы делают побитовый сдвиг. Для классов потоков они пределны как "прочитать" или "записать" данные. Я замечал переопределения таких операторов для вектора, чтобы было удобнее добавлять в него элементы. Например в Qt:

```
QVector<int> vec;
vec << 1 << 2 << 3;
```

Если вы будете писать свой класс, вы можете переопределить этот оператор, чтобы он делал что угодно. Например складывал параметры. Но это сильно не рекомендуется.

Comment: можно упомянуть, что визуально: `cin >> x` (что из `cin` (поток ввода) пишется в `x`) по направлению стрелочек ☞☞ данные идут и наоборот: `cout << x` (`x` пишется в `cout` (поток вывода))—снова по направлению стрелочек ☜☜ данные идут.

Answer (score 4):

Вот так решили в с++: вместо определения тривиальных методов с названиями read или write для классов потоков переопределить операции побитового сдвига таким образом, что с побитовым сдвигом они ничего общего не имеют. Красиво жить не запретишь! Польза операций по сравнению с методами, например, в более короткой записи конвейера:

```
поток << "ура, " << "вперед";
```

Короче, чем гипотетические

```
поток.write("ура, ");
поток.write("вперед");
```

Comment: Ничто не запрещает `write` возвращать ссылку на поток для обеспечения *цепочного* вызова вида: `поток.write("ура, ").write("вперед");`. И всё же, не "операции", а "операторы", и "функции-члены", а не "методы". Хотя с методами тут уже народ смирился.

Comment: @alexolut что бы вы изменили в языке, чтобы функции-члены можно было бы называть методами?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian для этого нужно прописать название в стандарт

Comment: @alexolut т.е. реальных причин не использовать термин "метод", кроме инертности стандарта нет?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian затрудняюсь сказать, возможно имеет смысл задать соответствующий вопрос, хотя не уверен, что его не закроют как "основан на мнениях" :)

Comment: @alexolut В классической русской терминологии математики и программирования "operator" - это все же "операция".  Операции - это сложение, вычитание, сдвиг и т.д. Операторы - это цикл, if и т.д, т.е. то, что на английском именуют "statement".  Другое дело, что кальки с английского почти всегда рано или поздно становятся традицией словоупотребления в программировании.